# $("#my_div").html('value'); not replacing in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using a simple JQuery call to replace some HTML in a DIV tag after an AJAX call.

```
$("#my_div").html('value');
```

This works great in the other browsers, but in IE it is just adding to the DIV instead of replacing the HTML.

Any ideas why that would happen?

Answer (score 2):

call `empty()` before `html()`

```
$("#my_div").empty().html('value')
```

I noticed that behavior quite a lot and `empty()` always fixes the issue.

Comment: That's weird. I though html() was supposed to replace in jQuery.

Comment: Comes down to "I thought IE was suppose to be a compliant web browser"

Comment: it's even more bizarre seeing how jQuery appears to be calling empty() internally for the html() function anyways

Comment: Maybe it's a DOM timing issue. Should be reported as jQuery bug.

Comment: For all jQuery's problems (and its implementation of `empty` is appalling), you shouldn't have to do this; Zarembisty is right. I would love to see a test case for this.